# Mongoose Document Array Not Updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document with a sub-array:

```
{
    'username': "student1",
    'appointment_requests': [
        {'semester': "SPRING 2015", ...},
        ...
    ]
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
user_model.update(
                { 'username': "student1", 'appointment_requests.semester' : 'SPRING 2015' }, 
                { $set: {'appointment_requests.$.status': this.REASSIGNED_STATUS, 'appointment_requests.$.submitted': moment().format()}}, 
                console.log
        );
```

This does (if I change the document to be 'SPRING2015'):

```
user_model.update(
                { 'username': "student1", 'appointment_requests.semester' : 'SPRING2015' }, // GOT RID OF SPACE!!
                { $set: {'appointment_requests.$.status': this.REASSIGNED_STATUS, 'appointment_requests.$.submitted': moment().format()}}, 
                console.log
        );
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a well known deficiency? Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

In both cases I get:

`null 1 { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }`

However, when I use "SPRING 2015", it doesn't work!

When I try to use update for a non existent student, I get:

`null 0 { ok: true, n: 0, updatedExisting: true }`

So Mongoose finds the doc, but Mongo never updates the doc?

EDIT:

I edited it with console, same result...

Seems like Mongo bug??

EDIT:

Do not have time to debug Mongo, making a work around with find and updating/saving manually...

Comment: try `'courses.semester'` instead of `'appointment_requests.semester'` and `'courses.$status'` instead of `'appointment_requests.$.status'`

Comment: @TamilSelvan My sample doc did not have proper names, updated.

Comment: Sample doc shows `student` as the key, but update statement shows `username`.

Comment: @brianShamblen, the sample doc was not a direct copy paste. Fixed.